# bulk Neo4j admin import from csv using regex

Tags: import, neo4j

I am trying to import data from multiple csv files by matching regex pattern into neo4j database instance by neo4j admin import method, which is probably the fastest way to import data in neo4j.

I am trying to use the below command to import the data in my neo4j database instance:

```
neo4j-admin database import full --nodes import/data_header.csv,import/data_\d+\.csv --overwrite-destination=true
```

But I am getting error something like this:

```
Invalid nodes file: import/data_header.csv,import/data_\d+\.csv (java.lang.IllegalStateException: Directory C:\Program Files\neo4j-community-5.12.0-windows\neo4j-community-5.12.0\import\data_\d+ of import/data_\d+\.csv doesn't exist)
```

I am trying to import the data from all files that start with data_ and have any number after it.
For example, a valid file would be `data_1.csv`.

I even tried with absolute path but that too did not yield any result.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, a backslash (`\`) in the path is taken to be a path-component separator. To treat is as a regular backslash, you need to escape it with another backslash.

This should work:

```
neo4j-admin database import full --nodes /import/data_header.csv,/import/data_\\d+.csv --overwrite-destination=true
```